# Too many redirects caused by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My web application has problem with too many redirets error (still reloading page). I tryied to delete cookies, didn't help.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Solved, problem was in PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
# turn directory trailing slash off
DirectorySlash Off
```

Because if you add it with the option and remove it with RewriteRule and redirect...

Comment: Could someone help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Choose one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
```

or add a closing

```
</IfModule>
```

---

Try using:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You have two opening `<IfModule *>`, but only one `</IfModule>`. So either you meant to only have one opening If or forgot to close the second.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. After adding `</IfModule>` now 500 error appears on the page.

Comment: I have edited my answer, try using that. I moved around the contents of the file to what you *probably* wanted.

Comment: Problem solved, there was buggy code at sessions stage. Thanks everyone work helping.